# Copying Double to a void pointer in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm copying a double value to a Void*.How can I do it in C++.

Currently I've tried in C++10

strcpy(Trade->MtTr.MPData->MPTrXML.da,dCou);

Trade->MtTr.MPData->MPTrXML.da-->this is a Void*

dCou is double.

strcpy(Trade->MtTr.MPData->MPTrXML.da,dCou);

I expect the void* should contain the double value.
In actual I'm getting error as:

error C2665: 'strcpy' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

while trying to match the argument list '(void *, double)'

Comment: What are you trying to achieve using `void*` ?

Comment: You must be doing something very unusual. Please tell us more.

Comment: C++ is a strict type checking language and such conversions are not automatic without (usually ill-functioning) casting.

Comment: Also, `strcpy` in C++? Come on!

Comment: The one reason I can think of for something like this is if dealing with some low-level `C` API that uses `void *` as a universal type.  Otherwise I don't see where this could/should be used in a pure C++ application.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar: The **really** bad thing is `strcpy` on binary data. Even in C, calling `strcpy` on a double is displaying a total lack of understanding. `strcpy` copies up to and including the first null byte, which may or may not be present in the  `double`. If it isn't, you have an out-of-bounds memory read which is Undefined Behavior. If the first null is not at the end of the double, only part of it is copied and the receiver will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid reason to be attempting to copy a `double` to a `void*`, then one way is to use [memcpy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
#include <cstring>
//..
// Assuming Trade->MtTr.MPData->MPTrXML.da is valid:
double dCou;
//...
memcpy(Trade->MtTr.MPData->MPTrXML.da, &dCou, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Thank you, @PaulMcKenzie it worked exactly as I required.